# Unable to Install Wrapped App using Microsoft Intune

Tags: intune

I am new to Microsoft Intune. I successfully enrolled my iOS and Android devices on Microsoft Intune.

I upload an iPA file and Apk file on Microsoft Intune and both are successfully installed on respective device.

Then I wrapped both apps using Microsoft Intune Wrapping Tool for iOS and Android and again upload both the apps. But Now i am unable to install these apps on devices. Apps download starts but at the end of the progress there is a error Failed to download.

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: This was likely a non-updated build number preventing install...

Comment: Did you signed again those files before uploading to Intunes?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit dated, but if this is still an issue, for iOS specifically, try wrapping the application and downloading it again, and as you do that, keep an eye at the log (from Xcode / Window / Devices). You may see some log lines that could indicate what the issue is, or at least get you in the right direction - possibly issues with your certificate, signing, and the like.